# Java RMI object static and not static field?

Tags: java, static, rmi

So I have this code:

```
public class RemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements TestRemote {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static int counter = 0;
    private int localizedCounter = 0;

    protected RemoteImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int getMeGlobalCounter() throws RemoteException {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMeLocalizedCounter() throws RemoteException {
        localizedCounter++;
        return localizedCounter;
    }
}
```

And with my Client I am trying:

```
public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", Constant.RMI_PORT);
        TestRemote remote = (TestRemote) registry.lookup(Constant.RMI_ID);
        System.out.println("Global counter:" + remote.getMeGlobalCounter());
        System.out.println("Localized counter:" + remote.getMeLocalizedCounter());
    }

}
```

After running this code for the 2 times I am expecting to see:

```
Global counter:3
Localized counter:1
```

however I see that

```
Localized counter:3
```

So why is the localized counter not reset everytime I invoke this method? Am I not getting a new object everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I not getting a new object every time?

No you aren't. You're getting the same instance that was bound into the Registry. RMI doesn't just create remote objects willy-nilly.

Comment: How can I achieve what I am trying?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying. If you're expecting to get a new remote object per lookup, you need to revise your expectations.

Comment: I want to get a new object everytime I run the client.

Comment: Then you're gong to have to code that yourself. You'll need a singleton remote object in the Registry that exports a method that creates a new instance of another remote object that implements another remote interface. Sort of remote factory pattern. Very wasteful of resources. I would try to change the problem myself.